# Using Eval on div inside DataList ItemTemplate for MouseOver?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I apologize for the convoluted title.

I have a `DataList` that looks like below:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataListFloor" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div style='width:199px;height:166px;background-color: <%# Eval("background") %>'>
            <div style="width: 199px; height: 22px; overflow: hidden;">
                <div style="box-sizing: border-box; width:97px; float:left;">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name")%>'></asp:Label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

And the datatable to bind to this `DataList` is:

```
Name    background  background_mouseOver
----------------------------------------
Joe     Yellow      Orange
Mary    white       Beige
Jane    Red         Maroon
Carl    gray        Darkgray
```

The `background-color` of the `div` is already set to the color in the column `background`. So I know that `Eval` for that attribute is working.

My question is: how can I change the `background-color` of the `div` on `MouseOver` to the value in `datatable` column `background_mouseOver`. So for example, for the datalist item that says *Joe*, the background-color will be *Yellow*. When I move my cursor over that cell, the background-color will change to *Orange*.

Please, no jquery.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `onMouseover` this way:

```
<div onMouseover="this.style.backgroundColor = '<%# Eval("background_mouseOver")%>'" style='background-color: <%# Eval("background") %>'>
</div>
```